# Anaconda3 not installing due to space in path

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Anaconda3 but it isn't getting installed due to blank space in the path name between "*Ganesh*" and "*Pawar*". What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to include screenshots, instead of photos of the screen? Please also use imgur to store your photos in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Anaconda3 cannot be installed using a path that includes a space - the "*solution*" is to install it elsewhere, e.g: `C:\anaconda`:

> #### In what folder should I install Anaconda on Windows?
>
> We recommend installing Anaconda or Miniconda into a directory that contains only 7-bit > ASCII characters and no spaces, such as `C:\anaconda`. Do not install into paths that > contain spaces such as `C:\Program Files` or that include Unicode characters outside the 7-> bit ASCII character set. This helps ensure correct operation and no errors when using any open source tools in either Python 3 or Python 2 conda environments.

This is rather unfortunate for users who have a space in their name:

> #### What is the default path for installing Anaconda?
>
> If you accept the default option to install Anaconda on the “default path” Anaconda is installed in your user home directory:
>
> Windows 10: `C:\Users\<your-username>\Anaconda3\`

Source: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/